# Is this a bug on PokerStars?

Tags: texas-hold-em

Pokerstars uses the forward moving button rule in cash games.

[I have recorded a video](http://youtu.be/Q57loLLqDY0) to try to show the exact situation when it happens. The first table shows myself leaving the game in the big blind position. The dealer moves to the next player as normally. In the second table i think is the same situation but different outcome. Anyone can explain why is the dealer button moving back (actually making another table round)?

Comment: The button is just moving to the small blind in each case.

Comment: On the first table yes, but on the second it moves back to the previous button. The guys from Pokerstars said it's one of those 'peculiar situations' but they didn't say anything decisive. I doubt its a hidden rule from the forward moving button system. It's not even that uncommon since it always happens when the small or big blind leaves in a 3-player-game and another joins before the next hand starts. Leaving as the small blind in the that situation leads to the same guy posting the big blind twice in a row.

Comment: Where the button is, is not based on where the button was. It is based on the first player to be dealt in. The button is always placed going counter clockwise from the first player to receive cards, to the first player eligible to receive a hand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a bug. Hold'em rules are pretty universal on this point: when the game is reduced to two players, the big blind for the next hand is paid by whoever paid the big blind least recently, and the other player posts the small blind and takes the button.

Answer (score 1):

if the 2nd table is left 2 handed this would explain why. In 2 handed game the button is the small blind